# Use count value in clause WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, count, having-clause

I want to add a WHERE clause to my SQL query. but if I add AND n! = 1, I get an error.

how do I proceed?

thank you

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS n,
    `prescription`.`id_prescription`
FROM
    `intervention`
LEFT JOIN
    `prescription`
ON
    `prescription`.`id_prescription` = `intervention`.`id_prescription`
WHERE
    `intervention`.`status` != "finish" AND `intervention`.`status` != "canceled" 
GROUP BY
    id_prescription  
ORDER BY `n`  DESC
```

> Erreur

Requête SQL : Documentation

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS n,
    `prescription`.`id_prescription`
FROM
    `intervention`
LEFT JOIN
    `prescription`
ON
    `prescription`.`id_prescription` = `intervention`.`id_prescription`
WHERE
    `intervention`.`status` != "finish" AND `intervention`.`status` != "canceled"  AND `n` !=1
GROUP BY
    id_prescription  
ORDER BY `n`  
DESC LIMIT 0, 25
```

MySQL a répondu: Documentation
#1054 - Champ 'n' inconnu dans where clause

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish would be helpful.  Your query has other errors/inconsistencies apart from the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Use `having` to filter on aggregates:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS n, id_prescription
FROM intervention i
LEFT JOIN prescription p USING(`id_prescription`)
WHERE i.status <> 'finish' AND i.status <> 'canceled'
GROUP BY id_prescription  
HAVING COUNT(*) <> 1
ORDER BY n  DESC
```

Side notes:

- table aliases make the query easier to write and read
- `USING()` comes handy to shorten the join syntax when the matching column(s) are homonyms
- backticks are probably not necessary here
- `<>` is the standard operator for inequality
- single quotes are the standard quoting character for literal strings
- MySQL extends the SQL standard and allows using column aliases in the `HAVING` clause, so you could also phrase it: `HAVING n <> 1`

Answer (score 0):

It seems very strange that you are aggregating by the *second* table in a `LEFT JOIN`.  If you want to count the number of interventions for each prescription, then your query should look like this:

```
SELECT p.id_prescription, COUNT(i.id_prescription) as num_interventions
FROM prescription p
     intervention i
     ON p.id_prescription = i.id_prescription AND
        i.stqatus NOT IN ('finish', 'canceled')
GROUP BY p.id_prescription  
HAVING COUNT(i.id_prescription) <> 1
ORDER BY COUNT(i.id_prescription) DESC;
```

This version of the query correctly returns `0` for the count when there are no interventions.  I suspect that the `HAVING` clause you really want is:

```
HAVING COUNT(i.id_prescription) > 1
```

And if this interpretation is correctly, then an `INNER JOIN` is a better option than a `LEFT JOIN`, because the logic requires a match.